# Terraform Error 'bool' is not a valid type

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm launching a GKE private cluster via terraform template and getting the following error

```
   Error: Error loading ~/projects/tf-gke/variables.tf: Variable 'private_cluster_config' type must be one of [string, map, list] - 'bool' is not a valid type
```

However according to their docs 'bool' type should exist https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#bool

My providers.tf file looks like this

```
provider "google" {
version = "~> 2.3"
project = "fantastic-cluster"
region = "australia-southeast1" }
```

Comment: `bool` is not a valid type until 0.12. Note the disclaimer at the top of the doc.

Comment: yeah, checked my terraform version and it's actually not the latest: terraform -v
Terraform v0.11.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed 'bool' type to 'string'. Value is still "true". Seems to be working.